# Signing bitcoin on blockcypher : "error": "Not enough signatures: 0 for 1 inputs"

Tags: php, api, curl, bitcoin, ethereum

I'm using blockcypher to make transactions. I've followed all the necessary steps but when I try and send the transaction I get back an error message, " error: Not enough signatures: 0 for 1 inputs".

**Signer (tosign & private key)**

go run signer.go 697817584637d858b16ceb4dbecddfb7afc2da67992263ccffa2891bf69bb229 8f16d5bae3c2e4b6923d5a7da8194088f1813f5b22900b9a648d7ef8a38d0be0

**Output Signature**

```
3044022005b5ee7e4bac8a16a1ed59b4132a5ed51633718425b2813430bff0dbf238b35602203b3345c013f0f6555b029bed886ace99cbf416300d6007775d8a4772205e5a0b
```

**Bitcoin Sender Information**

```
  private key:8f16d5bae3c2e4b6923d5a7da8194088f1813f5b22900b9a648d7ef8a38d0be0,  public key:029602113dd7851c8095434c4019258462aa30c16df6d146b9c4d039f1c5392f03,
address: mzrycPJMEjQ4WNv7rZVZepb6Lse63Xt4Ue,
  wif: cSNrA5tkpCpRLdXHrSy3mYdWRWPGFTYd53Z9tERz5DSprUx7JGZM
```

**Bitcoin Receiver Information**

```
private key:f392289723ef4a6dfef8fef7a76daea1cce8c572ed73d3b05e15271bfae70a01,   public key:020e3dc996e6cab4df26770b01b8f135322de2ef52c0b394e5c49dcf981d700db7,
 address: mmzsfMgMk4hejzv5ahuQULnMGQC4n7Wm3H,
 wif: cVkAus4uxWXhvcJVKovCj9Fpx2U2rftq7QVBU2vDsbQoZuwirtu9
```

**Sending Transaction**

```
curl -d '{
  "tx": {
    "block_height": -1,
    "block_index": -1,
    "hash": "f54241d7525acba9d1a2ba270c9e1627810676a95909f0d1c7f800dde1b33adf",
    "addresses": [
      "mzrycPJMEjQ4WNv7rZVZepb6Lse63Xt4Ue",
      "mmzsfMgMk4hejzv5ahuQULnMGQC4n7Wm3H"
    ],
    "total": 300400,
    "fees": 99600,
    "size": 119,
    "preference": "high",
    "relayed_by": "158.223.165.35",
    "received": "2017-06-11T16:21:01.407862694Z",
    "ver": 1,
    "lock_time": 0,
    "double_spend": false,
    "vin_sz": 1,
    "vout_sz": 2,
    "confirmations": 0,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "prev_hash": "d2cb465b74e3f57d64b584962ee557d9a623d38befd570e14686438cc25279ee",
        "output_index": 0,
        "script": "",
        "output_value": 400000,
        "sequence": 4294967295,
        "addresses": [
          "mzrycPJMEjQ4WNv7rZVZepb6Lse63Xt4Ue"
        ],
        "script_type": ""
      }
    ],
    "outputs": [
      {
        "value": 10,
        "script": "76a914471888d19d0148ab072d3707712e8de8f4dc724788ac",
        "addresses": [
          "mmzsfMgMk4hejzv5ahuQULnMGQC4n7Wm3H"
        ],
        "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash"
      },
      {
        "value": 300390,
        "script": "76a914d433cec679da5579b3fff61eefbb0ce70ae9221a88ac",
        "addresses": [
          "mzrycPJMEjQ4WNv7rZVZepb6Lse63Xt4Ue"
        ],
        "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash"
      }
    ]
  },
  "tosign": [
    "697817584637d858b16ceb4dbecddfb7afc2da67992263ccffa2891bf69bb229"
  ]
}, "tosign": [ "697817584637d858b16ceb4dbecddfb7afc2da67992263ccffa2891bf69bb229" ], "signatures": ["3044022005b5ee7e4bac8a16a1ed59b4132a5ed51633718425b2813430bff0dbf238b35602203b3345c013f0f6555b029bed886ace99cbf416300d6007775d8a4772205e5a0b"], "pubkeys": ["029602113dd7851c8095434c4019258462aa30c16df6d146b9c4d039f1c5392f03" ] }' https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/test3/txs/send?token=fcd13b49d1a4469e865707205e2022bc
```

I used my own token, but I've censored it for this post.

If someone is able to help with this issue I would appreciate it highly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's something wrong with your JSON document. The signatures and pubkeys arrays should be at the same level as the "tosign" we return. What you posted is actually invalid JSON, there's another "tosign" with the signatures and pubkeys outside of the main document. Looks like you just did an append. Should be something like:

```
{
  "tx": { ... },
  "tosign": ["..."],
  "pubkeys": ["..."],
  "signatures": ["..."]
}
```

Comment: For the CTO to answer my question at the weekend means a lot. You guys are doing a great job :-) .

Answer (score 0):

In last you have used tosign two times , while it should be used once 
just use one time

Comment: Welcome to SO! What you write looks rather like a comment than an answer, please edit according to the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask